# Adding Camera to a tab in android

Tags: android, tabs

I want to add camera to a tab in a way that once i click that tab, the camera will work immediately.
I tried to use similar way to buttons by setting onClickListener but it seems tabs differs from buttons when it comes to listeners.

Answer (score 0):

-May be this would help you.

-onselecting the tab you want to launch camera.. call `intent` class like this..

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(                                    
        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);        


((Activity) con).startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,                
        CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE); 

                                   `
```

-`Onactivity result` method of new tabhost call your desired code further...

-THanks!